# How to play video using json web service data in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I using the below code to play video file using web service,but it is not work.please correct the code to play video.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tnhd.in/load/2014/Anjaan/Oru%20Kan%20Jaadai%20BRrip%20-%20Anjaan%20HD.mp4"];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:url ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the url like so:

```
NSString *path = @"http://tnhd.in/load/2014/Anjaan/Oru%20Kan%20Jaadai%20BRrip%20-%20Anjaan%20HD.mp4";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
```

Or better so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tnhd.in/load/2014/Anjaan/Oru%20Kan%20Jaadai%20BRrip%20-%20Anjaan%20HD.mp4"];
```

and send it to your player